# Both :443 and :80

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https, port

I have some common configuration for both port 443 and port 80. But I want for port 443 some specific configuration (like turning `SSLEngine On`). How can I get this working?

Comment: How about having two separate virtual hosts for the two ports, but include a common config file in both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kerrek already mentioned, you can easily setup two VirtualHost directives for each, then put an Include directive in each pointing to a file with the common elements.

If the server is only hosting a single site, you can put the common elements in the global configuration and setup a virtual host for the https site with the additional directives for it.

Comment: The hard part is when you want any login/password entry to redirect to the ssl version of the site.

Comment: @Koos, sounds like something that can easily be put into the login webpages (if forms based) or a quick mod_rewrite directive.

Comment: I later found the ideal trick myself: A 402 handler (authentication required) which redirects to the ssl version.

Comment: @KoosvandenHout A 402 is a redirect, not the mechanism on the server which triggers it. You would need application logic of some kind issuing the 402, such as mod_rewrite or something in PHP/Perl/whatever.

Comment: 402 state is authentication required. You define a handler for this state (can be done in apache) which gives a different answer: the 302 (temporary redirect) to the SSL version. Can be done as a perl/php script.

Comment: 402 is not a state, it's an HTTP Response Code. Unauthenticated is an internal daemon state, to which the daemon might respond with an 402 code. From a user's prospective the nuances of daemon and protocol state might be lost, but from a system administrator or application developer point of view these are critical distinctions.